# How to modify pointer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I get feature as point geometry:

[image]

Then I try to modify this geometry (move point):

```js
this.modify = new Modify({
  features: new Collection([feature])
});
this.mapService.map.addInteraction(this.modify);
```

As result I got a blue pointer over main point. When I drag it the pointer is disappeared. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The blue style is the default style for the Modify interaction.  If it is obscuring the features you are moving you can specify a different style such as crosshair, for example https://codesandbox.io/s/modify-points-268dtj?file=/main.js

Comment: Mike, thank you for answering.